# COMBOBOX: Error de objeto no identificado o variable with no establecida

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, combobox

tengo un form que al inciar debe rellenar ciertos ComboBox, tengo problemas con unos en especial, los cuales se rellenan a partir de una función que invoca datos desde SQL SERVER. El asunto está en que cuando pongo la instrucción `Call llenarInstrumentos(cmbCVinstr)`en el evento `Initialize` y hago el `Load` del form, me marca el error siguiente:

`Se ha producido el error -2147352571(800200005) en tiempo de ejecución:
 No se puede configurar la propiedad List. Los tipos no coinciden`

Vale decir que  `cmbCVinstr` es un ejemplo de los combobox que utilizan esta rutina. La conexión al servidor se hace por aparte y es independiente de este form, por lo que el problema es este último. Dicha conexión se utliza para otros forms y rutinas similares alimentan correctamente esos forms, la diferencia primordial está en que esos forms que sí funcionan son una sola columna pero no sé si eso tenga algo que ver con que no reconozca el combobox.

Por último, haciendo pruebas con ese evento (borrando y agregando el comando) me di cuenta de que el problema es esa rutina específicamente porque fuera de ella todo corre con normalidad.

El código de la función es:

```
Sub llenarInstrumentos(ByVal cb As ComboBox)

instrumentos = "SELECT * FROM [pruebaEDGE].[dbo].[InstrumentosPiP] ORDER BY [TdValor] ASC"

 Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
 rs.Open instrumentos, cn
    If Not rs.EOF Then
     i = 0
     cb.ColumnCount = 3
     cb.ColumnWidths = "210 pt;0 pt;0 pt"
    Do Until rs.EOF
        With cb
        .AddItem rs.Fields("Descrip") & " (" & rs.Fields("TdValor") & ")", i
        .List(i, 1) = rs.Fields("Tipo")
        .List(i, 2) = rs.Fields("Id")
        End With
      i = i + 1
      rs.movenext
    Loop
    End If
 rs.Close
 Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: el combo esta configurado en modo multicolumnas?

Comment: No, porque el número de columnas varía. Pensaba que desde la función se puede configurar ¿o no?

Comment: no estaria seguro de eso. capaz que es una propiedad que se puede modificar solo en tiempo de diseño.. habria que ver la documentacion..

Comment: oh, ok. le echaré un vistazo a eso. Gracias :)

Comment: Ya cambié el `columncount` en modo diseño y aún me bota que no encuentra la propiedad `.list` (ni `.column`)

Comment: mmm... y el combobox es del mismo tipo que el que estas pasando? no vaya a ser que no sean del mismo tipo y por eso no funciona

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con 'del mismo tipo'? ¿El nombre del Combobox? ese no ha cambiado, tengo una versión anterior que sí funciona, el query cambia un poco `SELECT * FROM [pruebaEDGE].[dbo].[Instrumentos] ORDER BY [Instrumento] ASC`
 ` With cb
       .ColumnCount = 3
       .AddItem
        .Column(0, i) = rs.Fields("Instrumento") & " (" & rs.Fields("BMV") & ")"
        .Column(1, i) = rs.Fields("Tipo")
        .Column(2, i) = rs.Fields("Clave")
      End With`

Comment: esa sí funciona pero no encuentro la razón, es por el Query?

Comment: apa.. no habia notado eso.. puede ser.. estas seguro que este query devuelve las columnas que estas pidiendo, siempre? por ejemplo que no viene vacio?

Comment: justo acabo de ver eso, el query de `Tipo` tiene un Null al ordenarlo ¿Es por ese o todos deben ser NotNull ?

Comment: no creo que puedas pasarle un null a lista.. tal vez un ""